# "I wish I knew what was (is) wrong with my car" - which is correct? (subjunctive mood)

Tags: subjunctives, tense-agreement, wish

Which one of the two forms of verb will make the following sentence idiomatic?

> I wish I knew what _____ wrong with my car.

1. Is
2. Was

I think it should be **is** because the sentence is in subjunctive mood, but refers to a present situation, hence use of **is** is justified.

But in my book correct answer is **was**

Comment: Does scene happen in the past or present?

Comment: @Cardinal     in present

Comment: wish never takes present tense.

Comment: The subjunctive mood applies to the verb *know*, because *knowing* is the action that the person wishes. The word you are selecting is in the indicative mood, because the problem with the car is a fact, not a wish. Which tense depends on entirely on whether the problem is past or present. (Examples -- "I wish I knew what is wrong with my car, so I can find someone to fix it." -- "I wish I knew what was wrong with my car, before my brother sold it for parts.")

Comment: @epi English does not have subjunctive mood. That terminology is out of date. But even so, **I wish I knew** has zero to do with subjunctive mood. **I knew** = **simple past**. And **what is/what was** are simple present and simple past, respectively. .

Comment: @Lambie: I suggest that you carefully read the Wikipedia article on [English subjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive), which directly contradicts every single claim in your comment, and begins with the text "The subjunctive mood in English..."

Comment: @epl I have no idea who is upvoting your inaccurate comments. I do not need to read any Wikipedia article. And it is really an inflectional form. https://www.academia.edu/5303996/The_Subjunctive_Conundrum You might wan5t 6to do some **Reading** (old-fashioned use of an initial capital letter).

Comment: @Lambie: I also have no idea who upvoted my comments, but I might guess that it was someone who shares my frustration that you would cherry-pick a source from an author who shares your views, representing them as though they were a scholarly consensus, while admitting that you disregard a source that explains the real consensus. Perhaps you would take your objections to the editors of Wikipedia. If they agree to a permanent change to the article in favor of the ideas expressed in your reference, then I will revise my comments accordingly.

Comment: @epi Like I said, your first comment is inaccurate, there is nothing "subjunctive" about I wish I knew + a clause.

Comment: @Lambie: It seems that you hold certain ideas in opposition to mainstream consensus. I support your right to these opinions, but I suggest that you express them in a more appropriate venue, perhaps [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com). For someone learning English, it is deeply and disturbingly unhelpful to ask a simple question, and then to encounter a response that conflicts nearly universally with mainstream educational sources. In this context, I strongly suggest that you avoid comments such as "English does not have a subjective mood".

Comment: @epl And it is very odd for me to read comments full of odd-sounding turns of phrase. "opposition to mainstream consensus"? English does not have a subjunctive mood. And today's modern linguists no longer call it that. See that grammar guru: CoGel, of whatever the book is called.

Comment: @Lambie: The suggestion is that responses given here should be restricted to expressing an orthodox viewpoint. Unorthodox viewpoints taken from publications in academic journals are less helpful in this context, and are rather distracting, to be frank, to most anyone who would ask a question of this kind.

Answer (score 4):

The *wish* is irrelevant.

The *knew*, whether you call it subjunctive or past, is treated as past.

Normally, therefore, the verb in the embedded question "What is wrong with my car" would get backshifted to "what was wrong with my car", as others have said.

**But** English speakers don't always backshift, when the situation is still current.

So you will hear both *was* and *is* here. I think *was* is more natural, but *is* occurs too.

Comment: was and is changes the idea. I wish I knew can be followed by a clause with either was or is. by either one. Each has a different meaning.

Comment: @ColinFine: Are you suggesting that the subjunctive mood of the clause subordinate to *wish* affects the form of not only *know/knew* but also *is/was*? Note that *know* is not describing a past event, otherwise *wish* would not appear in a present form.

Comment: *Wish* defines the grammar of *know* as a predicate of the past subjunctive clause for conveying the idea of the present. *Knew* defines the grammar of *is/was* as a subordinate clause which may have a backshifted predicate according to the rules of style being similar to those of the indirect speech clauses. That is why the choice between *is/was* sometimes is made for the former in some contexts, for example, in engineering and machinery. This is a gist of the OP in the case.

Comment: I might try to push back against the sense of "Normally... 'is'... would be backshifted to 'was'". Following Cambridge Grammar, criteria for favoring use of backshifting seem to be 1) subordinate clause expresses reported events, 2) main verb describes past action, and 3) main verb appears in past-tense form. Among these, only (3) is clearly true of this example, but only because of modal remoteness, which does not appear generally to introduce a context for backshifting being appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

**2. Was** seems more correct to me. Since "knew" is past-tense, the same tense should be used. It's understood that the car still isn't working because you're making the wish now.

Comment: Both are correct.

Answer (score 0):

"Was" is correct because the sentence the verb "to be" refers here to an alternative reality where the speaker possesses the knowledge of what is wrong with the car (i.e., irrealis mood).

This bit from Wikipedia is relevant to the topic at hand:

> "For most verbs, the only distinct subjunctive form is found in the
> third person singular of the present tense, where the subjunctive
> lacks the -s ending: It is necessary that he see a doctor (contrasted
> with the indicative he sees). **The verb be, however, has not only a
> distinct present subjunctive (be, as in I suggest that he be removed)
> but also a past subjunctive were (as in If he were rich, …).**
>
> These two tenses of the subjunctive have no particular connection in
> meaning with present and past time. Terminology varies; sometimes what
> is called the present subjunctive here is referred to simply as the
> subjunctive, and **the form were may be treated just as an alternative
> irrealis form of was rather than a past subjunctive**. "[English subjunctive - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive)

As further evidence that the tense doesn't necessarily refer to time period in this case, I can imagine a scenario where a speaker would say "I wish I knew what was wrong ..." in reference to a *future* event (e.g., discussing an upcoming competition like a hackathon or something).

Comment: Both are correct.

Answer (score 0):

The verb of your sentence is not "knew" but "wish", and yes, it is in the subjunctive mood.  Since your sentence is referring to the immediate situation, you are correct and the book is wrong.  People often slur their pronunciations in situations like this, by using a contraction.

```
I wish I knew what's wrong with the car.
```

Comment: A main verb may not appear in subjunctive form.

Answer (score 0):

**PART ONE**
The verb wish as in I wish [etc.] can never be followed by a present tense.

Usage examples:

**I wish I knew** his sister. [simple past]
**I wish I had known** his sister [past perfect] when the accident occurred.
**I wish I was/were** rich. The verb be can be was or were for third person singular.
**I wish I was/were going** with you.
I wish I knew what is wrong with you.

Here is **a simple rule**: Never use a present tense after wish when it is expressing a wish.
If you follow that rule, you will never make a mistake.

The tenses to use are: simple past, past continuous for expressing **a wish in the present time**
past perfect or past perfect continuous for expressing a wish about the past or with I wished [we had gone.

There are also some modals that can be but let's leave that for another day.

For example:I wish he **could have been** on time.

The verb wish is an oddity. It is the way it is.

**PART TWO**

**I wish I knew** [today] **what is wrong** [now or today] with my car.

**I wish I knew [today] what **was wrong** [at some past time] with my car.

Conclusion: **They are both correct and each means something different.**

Here are many more [examples](https://www.english-at-home.com/grammar/using-wish/#:%7E:text=English%20speakers%20use%20%E2%80%9Cwish%E2%80%9D%20to,past%20simple%20or%20past%20continuous.&text=You%20can%20also%20use%20%E2%80%9Cwish%E2%80%9D%20with%20modal%20verbs%20in%20English.).

Comment: True, but all irrelevant. He's not asking about the tense of _know_ but of _is/was_.

Comment: @ColinFine Right, I have now made it relevant. Thanks.

Comment: @epl: so please show us a sentence _in current English_ where _wish_ is followed by a present tense.

Comment: @CollinFine: Yes, I understand your objection. I would narrow the scope of my comments to more accurately represent the actual concern, which is that whereas the original question addresses the distinction of mood, the above response rather emphasizes tense. This discrepancy may generate confusion over a relation between the two categories, in particular, that subjective mood generally requires a past tense. A response that clarifies the issue directly, separate from the specific case of the verb *to wish*, may serve as a more productive educational tool.

Comment: A sentence where *wish* is followed by a present tense. Maybe this way, pls show us a sentence in current English where *wish* is followed by a present tense as it is in the OP. There are many, for example, *I wish I knew then what I know now* (The title of a book for teachers).

Comment: @Lambie I can't agree. Collin Fine is always accurate with the logic of own statements. Pls, look at the first comment of this string. Though, I can't rule out that some comments from the string have been deleted.

Comment: @ Lambie Thanks for the explanation. What am I doing? Bugging you. Pls, stop making me laugh. Sorry. I don't need it in any way at all. You, not me, asked me a question.

Comment: @Lambie Sorry. What about  *That is not what Colin meant...* And let's stop arguing. There is no reason at all.

Comment: @kngram That is not a question!!

Comment: @Lambie This verb has a specific polite pattern in some usages which you, it seems, didn't meet before.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a case of the weirdness of English subjunctive. Your book is correct that "was" is the correct choice, regardless of whether the problem is in the present, because "was/were" is also the subjunctive form of the verb "to be". The "was" (as well as the "knew") does not refer to past in this case, but the alternate reality where the knowledge is possessed.

As Benjamin notes, native speakers likely would shorten to

> I wish I knew what's wrong with my car.

The ambiguity here is that "what's" could be a contraction of either "what is" or "what was" and only context tells you which it is.

Comment: I wish I knew [in a present time, now] what **is** wrong with it [today]. **versus** I wish I knew [in a present time, now] what **was** wrong with it [yesterday or last week or when it broke down].

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence should read:

> I wish I knew what was wrong with my car.

"I wish I knew" goes together.

"Knew" is past tense. Because "knew" is past tense, you also have to use the past tense "was" in "what was wrong with my car."

To change it to present tense, you can say:

> I would like to know what is wrong with my car.

I'm not quite sure why the English language works this way but it does.

Answer (score -2):

Many consider it necessary to use *was* in such a grammar construction. Although, the same people allow the use of *is* in such a case, when the car remains to function improperly at the time of expressing this regret about it. So, the choice depends on the style of the accepted usage in a professional circle, where you use this grammatical construction.

*Wish* defines the grammar of *know* as the past tense clause for conveying the idea of the present. *Knew* defines the grammar of *is/was* as a subordinate clause which may have a backshifted tense according to the rules of style being similar to those of the indirect speech clauses. That is why the choice between *is/was* sometimes is made for the former in some contexts, for example, in engineering and machinery. This is a gist of the OP in the case.